# ValueError: Network is missing required field(s): chainid

Tags: web3.py, brownie

When adding another network it doesn't recognize the chainid for some reason.

```
root@DESKTOP-MIQQV4H:/mnt/c/users/user/documents/Blockchain/brownie_fund_me# brownie networks add Ethereum ganache-local host=http://127.0.0.1:8545 chaindid=5777
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

  File "brownie/_cli/__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "brownie/_cli/networks.py", line 68, in main
    fn(*args["<arguments>"])
  File "brownie/_cli/networks.py", line 138, in _add
    _validate_network(new, PROD_REQUIRED)
  File "brownie/_cli/networks.py", line 320, in _validate_network
    raise ValueError(f"Network is missing required field(s): {', '.join(missing)}")
ValueError: Network is missing required field(s): chainid
```

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Chain id of default private chain id 1337

Answer (score 1):

You must put value for "chainid" in add network command, but it seems to be the wrong name "chaindid", remove a wrong 'd' and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

> brownie networks add development mainnet-fork cmd=ganache-cli host=http:127.0.0.1 fork= accounts=10 mnemonic=brownie port=7545

This didn't ask me to provide chain ID